# Magento 1.x installation Error

Tags: magento, installation, magento-1.9, magento-2.0

Did magento removed 1.x after releasing magento 2, I am getting 404 error during download from this:
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz

Is there any alternative to use Magento 1.x, because the extensions which i am planning to use is not compatible with magento 2.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer use wget to get magento (at least from the official Magento's website). You have to follow this link: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download and then click on the 'Release Archive' tab. There you can find and download magento **v1.9.2.4** (and other previous releases) in various formats (zip, gz, bz2) . After download completes, you can upload it to your webserver and install it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get magento 1 from here
https://www.openmage.org/.

They have latest disponible stable version of magento 1.